# What is the difference between DL fonts and FM fonts?

Tags: fonts, character-encoding, nlp

There are different kind of fonts to download with different prefix such as FM, DL, FS and etc. what are the differences between them ? what do FM and DL stand for ?

Comment: I think it is the encoding. Something like "Latin-1/Latin-2/etc. But it could also be the style of language (how/if display a group of letters in a different manner). Possibly the easy way it is to download and test them (first case: same letters, in different order), second case, you will see stylistic difference)